# how to check the current host appears in a variable list within ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to run a microservice role multiple times against hosts to install multiple services. I would also like to use ansible to move services around. This implies that I run against `all` my hosts and do some logic to check whether the service is installed and whether it should be installed.

I am finding it easy to check whether the service is or isn't installed. What I am doing to check whether the service should be installed is clunky. In my playbook I defined a list of hosts that should have the role installed:

```
roles:
    - {
      role: "ansible-role-springboot",
      sb_app_name: "microservices-registration",
      sb_app_group_id: "org.springframework.samples.service.service",
      sb_app_artifact_id: "microservices-demo",
      sb_app_version: "2.0.0.RELEASE",
      sb_hosts: [
        "my-test-vm"
      ]
    }
```

Then I am wanting to test a fact "is the current host in the list?". With my particular test kitchen ansible setup the inventory_hostname is always coming out as `localhost` even though the vm has the correct hostname. So I am wanting to test the output of the command `hostname -f` is in var list `sb_hosts`. This is what I have come up with:

```
- name: Transfer the script
  copy: src=host_test.sh dest=/home/sbuser mode=0777

- name: Resolve hostname
  command: "/home/sbuser/host_test.sh {{ sb_hosts }}"
  register: hostname_output

- set_fact: 
    hostname_listed="{{ 'HOSTNAME_LISTED' in hostname_output.stdout}}"
```

Where `host_test.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOSTNAME=$(hostname -f)
VARS=$1
if echo $VARS | grep $HOSTNAME; then
    echo HOSTNAME_LISTED
else
    echo HOSTNAME_NOT_LISTED
fi
```

Copying a shell script to do something so basic feels very clunky. Is there a cleaner way to check "is is variable scalar within this variable list"?

Comment: You have failed to include the actual jinja2 snippet that is failing for you, in order for us to help you debug it. If `{{ inventory_hostname in sb_hosts }}` is false, then perhaps `{{ ansible_hostname in sb_hosts }}` or `{{ ansible_nodename ... }}`, or the catch-all `{{ ([inventory_hostname, ansible_hostname, etcetc] | intersect(sb_hosts) | length) != 0 }}`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Thanks that really helped a `inventory_hostname` was localhost but `ansible_hostname` is set correctly so the j2 that works is `sb_app_state="{% if ansible_hostname in sb_hosts %}present{% else %}absent{% endif %}"`. If you would supply an answer that matches your comment that there are other standard vars that can be checked then i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `{{ inventory_hostname in sb_hosts }}` is false, then perhaps `{{ ansible_hostname in sb_hosts }}` or `{{ ansible_nodename ...etc... }}`, or the catch-all `{{ ([inventory_hostname, ansible_hostname, etcetc] | intersect(sb_hosts) | length) != 0 }}`

You can obtain a full list of the names that ansible knows about via the `setup` command, or by dumping `- debug: var=hostvars` to see what fun toys are hiding in there.

If there is a catalog of the available `hostvars` populated by `setup`, then I don't know off-hand where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In finally went with:

```
ansible_hostname in sb_hosts
```